# Coldfusion, using GetHttpRequestData, to Store and Handle Files

Tags: coldfusion, xmlhttprequest, cffile, cfimage

I have a JQUERY file upload plug-in which allows users to upload files to the Coldfusion server. The plugin submits the files to the server in a way that requires me to use GetHttpRequestData() for the files contents. Here's what I have so far in terms of handling the file data:

```
<cfparam name="URL.qqfile" type="string">
<cfset x = GetHttpRequestData()>
<cffile action="write" output="#x.content#" file="c:\temp\#URL.qqfile#">
```

This works, which is nice, but I can't seem to take this to the next step.

What I want to happen next is:
A. Determine the file's extension.
B. If it is an accepted ext defined by my app, (JPG,PNG,PDF, DOC, DOCX, etc...) upload it to the correct directory on the server. Then delete the temp file above
C. Use CFIMAGE to make a thumbnail if the file uploaded was an Image

How can I take the above through steps A-C with the GetHttpRequestData problem?

Thanks

Comment: From you other thread, the behavior seems to be browser dependent. So you may want to use a test like <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "nameOfFileField")> do normal cffile upload <cfelse> do other file handling ... </cfif>

Comment: Sadly this still is not working. Any ideas? I'd love to see a page that shows how to handle GetHttpRequestData() from the AJAX Upload plugin

Comment: Why do you have to use GetHttpRequestData()? I use jQuery to upload images to a CF server side and use cffile.

Answer (score 3):

A few tips:

- Have a look at the result structure of `GetHttpRequestData()` via `<cfdump>`.
- Pull out the necessary headers by accessing this struct. The Content-Type header usually contains the stuff you want to know. You can use the [List functions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_13.html) (i.e. `ListLen()`, `ListFirst()`, `ListLast()`, `ListRest()` with appropriate delimiter chars) to easily parse the string.
- Always use `StructKeyExists()` to safeguard against missing struct parts. Never take for granted anything that "typically" seems to be in this struct.
- Don't blindly trust file extensions or the Content-Type header. Also look into the first few bytes of the uploaded file and compare them against a white list to confirm the file type.
- Have a look at `<cffile action="upload">`.
- Optionally, [perfom a drive space test](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace()) to assess if the uploaded data does not clog the server, or enforce limits in another way that suits you.
- Read through the documentation of `<cfimage>`. It can't be *that* hard to use it to make thumbnails.

Comment: Making thumbnails isn't hard at all.

Comment: +1 to: "Don't blindly trust file extensions or the Content-Type header ..".  Some other security tips for file uploads can be found here http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm